# ipa for App Store "ApplicationVerificationError"

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

My app runs fine in debug mode in FlashDevelop.

When I try to export it for the app store using my dist. files,
the ipa is created but it does not get installed. I get the error:

```
ApplicationVerificationError
```

However, the same ipa created there, I'm able to send it for review and its accepted. I don't know what the response from Apple will be, maybe it will be rejected.

What do you think? Is this only a local error and my ipa will pass the review?

Comment: IPA created with Appstore provisioning profile cannot be installed on our devices. It is meant to be installed only on test devices at Apple.

Comment: so you think the folks at apple will be able to install my ipa without problems for review?

Comment: Yes, if your IPA is submitted successfully, after validation via Xcode.

Comment: I created it with FlashDevelop, and uploaded it via App Loader from a Mac. It passed all the validations just like in xcode.

Comment: If it passes all validation, then you should not worry.